# Android WebViewClient not returning proper error

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a `WebView` in my code which uses a custom `WebViewClient`. I have overridden various error methods in my `CustomWebViewClient` file.

```
public  class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                              String description, String failingUrl) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  @Override
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  @Override
  public void onReceivedHttpError(
      WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
  }
}
```

Now, I want to handle various types of errors in my WebView. I tried with the following scenarios.

1) Load a local html **"file:///android_asset/main.html"** which does not exist.

-- In this scenario, I am getting callback to the first method i.e. `OnReceivedError()`.

2) Load a html page hosted on the web i.e. **http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.ht**. This html also does not exist. But in this case I am not getting any callback to the error method.

While inspecting on the Chrome, I am getting the following error

GET http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.ht 404 (Not Found), which clearly shows that the resource is not available. Then why is the WebView not returning any callback for errors ?

---

In both the cases, I am requesting a resource which is not available. But I am getting error callbacks only in the first scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have run on a device whose api is < 23. 
The url http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.ht
returns callback to onReceiveHttpError(). But this method is only added from API level 23.
[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceResponse))

Comment: Thanks for the info. But is there no way to get the http error below Marshmallow ?